Issue with Inline editing Datatable Lightning web component with values populated from wrapper class
I have been facing an issue with saving a Datatable with inline editing. The data is a combination of parent and child objects. Hence I had to add a wrapper class to pass the data to the lightning component. No issue with getting the data displayed onto the datatable. I have set these fields to be editable.
However when I try saving the records using onsave it does not seem to save it. What I found is event.detail.draftValues array seem to contain only "row-0" instead of the record Id. The issue seems to be only when I use wrapper class. However when I try avoiding the wrapper class I can see the recordId in event.detail.draftValues which means that I cannot use the field from parent object.
Any help around this is much appreciated.
My code is as follows
@api recordId;
contactData =[];
columns = COLS;
draftValues = [];
contactRefreshProp;
    @wire(getContacts, {
        accId : '$recordId'
    })
    getContactOutput(result) {
        this.contactRefreshProp = result;
        if(result.data) {
            this.contactData = result.data;
        } 
        else if(result.error) {
        }
    }

    async saveHandler(event) {
         let records = event.detail.draftValues 
         let updateRecordsArray = records.map(currItem => {
            let fieldInput = {...currItem}
            return {
                fields:fieldInput
            };
         });
         this.draftValues = [];
         let updateRecordsArrayPromise = updateRecordsArray.map(currItem => 
            updateRecord(currItem));
         await Promise.all(updateRecordsArrayPromise);
         const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Success",
            message:
                "Records Updated Successfully",
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
        await refreshApex(this.contactRefreshProp);
    }
}


I am seeing the error Error: Invalid recordInput in the console logs. event.detail.draftValues has
0: {Id@ 'row-0', Designation: 'Arch' }. I need the recordId instead of 'row-0'

In my experience, the Id in the Draft Values is the one you set as the key-field="id". Sounds like you aren't doing that so it is assigning a unique Id for you. So I would check you are setting the key field correctly

Thank you very much @BritishBoyinDC. You were right. It was the reference key-field ="id"
